# Can someone help me finish installing Ubuntu on my partitioned hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, software-installation

I currently have windows 8.1 and I had someone partition it for me and let me to download the newest Ubuntu and install in on the partioned drive D:   everything installed right, then after rebooting and loading into Ubuntu the screen says ~ Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.    ~  If I ignore, it then says ~ Disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present   ~     H E L P !?!?   THANKS !

J

Comment: ...If you still got the live USB or CD (from which ubuntu was installed) try to "repair ubuntu" from it. You need to boot from this USB/CD, open up "install ubuntu" then you should find "repair ubuntu...".

...Tell me if you didn't understand anything from what I said

Comment: I downloaded the .iso and used that. The cd i got in the book had a much older version. like 9.04 or someshit....

Comment: mmm okay how did you use this .iso you downloaded?

Comment: shoot. not sure if it was .iso or not. whatever files you get when u download Ubuntu then. i extracted it into my new partioned drive D:

Comment: ...so after that you booted up the ubuntu installation from your drive D?

Comment: ...okay try Karel's link

Comment: yes. ok thanks i'll try karels link THANKS GUYS !

Comment: cheers. hope it works :)

Comment: Can not move /tmp   Read-only file-system...

Comment: Can be of some help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Comment: Karel, it says that i can not move /tmp to /tmp_old: Read-only file-system... ??